# Relation between momentum and number of collisions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, momentum, scattering

I was wondering there exists any mathematical relation between momentum of a photon (hence frequency) and the number of collisions it makes. Lets consider the case of the ionosphere where we have a large sample of free electron naturally existing. Let waves of 2 different frequencies be incident on the ionosphere.

Is it correct to say that photons of higher frequency wave (lower wavelength) makes more collisions in the ionosphere than the lower frequency counterpart since the former possess higher momentum (using $p=h/ \lambda$ )than the latter. It is assumed that both the frequencies traverse through the same path of the ionosphere so that it encounters the same density of electrons.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Why do you doubt it?

Comment: well its because in ionospheric physics, it is observed that high frequency waves are less attenuated than low frequency waves - a complete contradiction to the particle picture.